# What will be stored in the instruction pointer during a jmp instruction in x64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

Consider a simple jump instruction (jmp) in assembly, where destination is a pre-defined label.

```
jmp destination
```

According to Kip Irvine's "Assembly Language for x86 Processors" when the CPU executes an unconditional transfer, the offset of *destination* is moved into the instruction pointer.

Could someone explain this because I thought the address to which we want to jump must moved into the instruction pointer?

Comment: What's the difference between "the address to which we want to jump" and "the offset (address) of destination"?

Comment: Well, is the absolute address stored in the instruction pointer ore an offset to another value?

Comment: IIRC the value in IP is, the address of the codesegment+the adress of the jmp-label. This is always the case. So in our  times, this might be already automatically done, but in former times this means: address, where codesegement starts + adress of jmp label ( hence the word offset).

Comment: x86 is a segmented architecture. While in long mode segmentation is forced to a flat model, the mechanism is still there. So technically the `ip/eip/rip` always holds the offset part of the logical (segment:offset) address. In practice since the segment starts at 0, the offset is also the linear address. Don't be confused with the offset encoded in the immediate, this is the number added to the current value of IP to reach the target.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the quote from the book?  Without context, it is difficult to answer this question

Comment: Never mind, I found it.  I completely understand why you were confused now.  See my answer for an explanation and the relevant quote from the book.  (Also, regarding the above comments, their use of "offset" didn't have anything to do with segments, but rather with the instruction encoding)

Comment: Thanks user1354557 for your great reply. Next time I will include the quote from the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the passage you're talking about:

> 4.5.1 JMP Instruction
>
> The JMP instruction causes an unconditional transfer to a destination, identified by a code label that is translated by the assembler into an offset. The syntax is
>
> JMP destination
>
> When the CPU executes an unconditional transfer, **the offset of destination is moved into the instruction pointer**, causing execution to continue at the new location.

Your confusion is understandable; this is poorly explained.

---

First of all, if an instruction says `jmp destination`, then it will set the instruction pointer equal to `destination`.  You're right about that.

But the instruction behavior is being confused with the instruction *encoding*.

---

Instructions of the form `jmp address` are encoded using **relative offsets** in x86.  The offsets are relative to the address *immediately following* the `jmp` instruction.

This can be encoded either as an `EB` followed by a signed byte offset or an `E9` followed by a signed dword offset. (Integers are [little endian](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html) in x86)

For example,

```
00010000:  EB 01 CC 90
```

Disassembles to

```
loc_10000:
    jmp loc_10003  ; EB 01
    int3           ; CC
loc_10003:
    nop            ; 90
```

And

```
00010000:  E9 01 00 00 00 CC 90
```

Disassembles to

```
loc_10000:
    jmp loc_10006  ; E9 01 00 00 00
    int3           ; CC
loc_10006:
    nop            ; 90
```

Note that this means instructions written the same way may have different encodings when located at different addresses.  For example,

```
00010000:  EB 02 EB 00 CC EB FD EB FB
```

Disassembles to

```
loc_10000:
    jmp loc_10004  ; EB 02
    jmp loc_10004  ; EB 00
loc_10004:
    int3           ; CC
    jmp loc_10004  ; EB FD   (FD == -3)
    jmp loc_10004  ; EB FB   (FB == -5)
```

Side note: There are several different forms of the `jmp` instruction, but the type you are speaking of can only be encoded with a relative offset.

---

Anyway, what the author is saying is that, for an assembler to generate machine code for an instruction like `jmp destination`, it must convert `destination` to a byte offset relative to the end of the `jmp` instruction.  Most of the time, you don't need to worry about this process, however.  You can just define a label in your assembly and write `jmp my_label`, and the assembler will take care of everything for you.

Comment: When they say "offset" there, they mean "offset from the CS segment base" (which is normally 0 outside of 16bit code), not the relative displacement used in the machine encoding.  All addresses in x86 are called offsets, except for "far pointers" which include a segment and offset.  e.g. [the `jmp ptr16:32`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html) form that has an immediate absolute address.

Answer (score 1):

consider this fake machine

```
address:    bytes:       comment:
0x0004      01 20 00     ; jmp destination  ; here ip = 0x0004
0x0007      ?? repeated 0x19 times
destination:
0x0020      02           ; hlt  ; here ip = 0x0020
```

compiled from this source:

```
    .code
    org  0x0004
    jmp destination
    org  0x0020
destination:
    hlt
```

So the symbol `destination` here means absolute address `0x0020` in section `.code` (which I won't give any special meaning, but you can imagine whatever complex construction as you wish, for example see segment registers in 16b mode of x86).

Then if the instruction with code 0x01 `jmp` is "near", only offset of that absolute address is used, which is 0x0020 in this simple fake example.

You can still have other variants of `jmp` on your CPU, like "relative" 0x03 `jmp rel8` capable to jump -128..+127 bytes from current `ip`, or "far" 0x04 `jmp bank/segment:offset`, which would set not only `ip`, but also some banking/segment mechanism.

So that word "offset" points to an era of `segment:offset` addressing, where full instruction pointer on x86 is `cs:ip`, not just `ip`. (cs = code segment)

In modern 32/64b x86 OS you usually don't have to touch `cs`, and work only with offsets inside 32/64b flat virtual memory mapping, then "address" has the same meaning as "offset of address".

Comment: I don't see the value in creating a fake architecture like the one above to answer this question when 1) he already mentioned x86, and 2) absolute direct jumps do not exist in x86

Comment: @user1354557 I have to confess... I can't hold a sh*t in my head (or maybe only that I can), so whenever I do x86, I have to imitate everything I see around in older code, or re-read the instruction guide. I was lazy this time, so I rather added some fake machine just to explain what the word "offset" means in this context. (btw `JMP m16:32` is quite close to it, except being something completely different and indirect).